# Textanalysen, Textproduktionen - Why plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

The introduction of the passage:

> Schriftliche **Textanalysen** und **Textproduktionen** sind ein entscheidender und doch inzwischen häufig vernachlässigter Teil des Spracherwerbs.

Later in the passage:

> Leider wird die **Textanalyse** inzwischen aus Zeitgründen oft hintangestellt, um automatisierten Prüfungsmethoden wie z. B. Multiple-Choice-Aufgaben Platz zu machen. Das Plädoyer für die **Textanalyse** ist eindeutig eines für die allein auf das eigene Wissen beschränkte Äußerung.

At first I try to google the term `Textanalysen` and `Textproduktionen`, but those plural forms don't show up very often, even this [happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOsgZ.png). With regard to the first sentence above, is the sentence semantically or grammatically incorrect? Because I couldn't really find out why one would use such nouns in plural, and then in the rest of the passage only the singular forms of the two are used.

Comment: You might have better search results if you drop the "Text" from "Analysen" and "Produktionen"; the "Text" only tells you what is being analyzed. The first example seems like jargon, and jargon often uses common words in uncommon ways. An example in English is "behaviors", which is specific to psychological jargon.

Comment: A much better understandable phrasing instead of teh didactics(?) jargon would be "Schriftliche Analysen und das Schreiben von Texten..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With regard to the first sentence above, is the sentence semantically or grammatically incorrect?

No, the sentence - in fact both sentences - are correct. Correct not only in a grammatical but also semantic sense.

The words are probably hard to find because German creates compounds *on the fly*. "Textanalysen" = *analyses of text(s)", "Textproduktionen" = *productions of text(s)* (basically, the last means what american pupils would call "creative writing").

> Because I couldn't really find out why one would use such nouns in plural, and then in the rest of the passage only the singular forms of the two are used.

There is a small but important difference in meaning and German is in this respect quite similar to English. The singular denotes the activity itself. i.e:

> *In der Textanalyse ist es wichtig ...*
> <sub>In text analysis it is important to ...</sub>

The plural is used when not the activity but *acts of* the activity are talked about. i.e:

> In *der Textanalyse* **ist** es wichtig, präzise zu sein und in dieser Hinsicht **sind** *deine Textanalysen* besser als seine.
> <sub>In *text analysis* it **is** important [singular, up to here we talk about the activity] to be precise and in this respect your *text analyses* **are** [plural, because we talk about (several) individual acts] better than his.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is correct and can be said like that. I don't know exactly why it is plural, but I believe it is either because there could be multiple variants of "Textanalysen" or because you will most likely do it multiple times. But as a German speaker, the plural just sounds correct while it would sound weird in the singular. You could use singular in a sentence like this:

> Die Textanalyse ist ein wichtiger Teil des Spracherwerbs.